# New version of jQuery loads another page instead of replacing div

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I don't know what I did wrong, but by updating to a newer version of jQuery, my ajax page doesn't work anymore.

I was using 1.8.3 from google CDN and now I'm trying to use 1.9.1. I have also updated jQuery UI to the 1.9.2 also from the google CDN. Finally, I have taken the latest "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" for my page.

Everything works fine on my website, except the page where I use ajax call to replace div on my page. This page was working perfectly but now when the user click submit, it just load into another page.

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zkhKC/#) that simplify my page a lot. I don't know how to call a "fake controller" in jsfiddle that could return simple html so modify it if you want. By clicking the button, it's supposed to replace the div with the same GUID. The Ajax call has been generated with the Ajax object from MVC 3. Like this:

```
 using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddSubtitle", "Recipe",
                    new AjaxOptions 
                    { 
                        UpdateTargetId = superGuid,
                        HttpMethod = "POST",
                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                        OnSuccess = "done"
                    }))
                {
                    <input type="hidden" name="IDRecipe" value="@Model.IDRecipe" />
                    <a name="SubtitleSection" ></a>
                    <input class="field required span6 text-box single-line" name="Name" />
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Ajouter une catégorie d'ingrédient" />
                }
```

My controller seems to work very well since in the new page that opens the content is perfect. Here it is so that you have all the piece of the puzzle.

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public PartialViewResult AddSubtitle(Subtitle sub)
{
    Recipe realRecipe = db.Recipes.Find(sub.IDRecipe);

    if ((Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey == realRecipe.IDUser || User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        sub.Order = realRecipe.Subtitles.Count + 1;
        if (sub.Name != null && sub.Name != "")
        {
            realRecipe.Subtitles.Add(sub);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Le nom de la catégorie ne peut pas être vide!");

        return PartialView("_SubtitleList", Utils.GetListIngredientAndSubtitle(realRecipe.IDRecipe, realRecipe.Subtitles));
    }
    else
        return PartialView("_SubtitleList", null);
}
```

Anybody can help me with this?

Comment: Anything in the browser console once the page loads?

Comment: Error using linked jsFiddle: "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live' "  Live is deprecated, use delegation with .on(). To migrate unobtrusive-ajax plugin, you could use: http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/01/jquery-migrate-1-2-0-released/

Comment: I was testing with chrome and it didn't show me this error. Just try with IE and go the same error as @roasted. I will try his link and see if it help!

Comment: I have this error using your linked jsFiddle and chrome. But this error is not relative to browser but to jquery version. BTW, are you using the console? Because only IE show alert message on debug error.

Comment: The trick with the jquery-migrate-1-2-0 did it! Wow thanks! But is this a good practice to use this? Also, you could write an answer so I can give you credit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right your page behaves as if there's no ajax because Unobtrusive failed. Make sure you update the version of **Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax** - older versions use the  deprecated .live() method as mentioned, but the new one is updated with .on()

Install:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax
```

[Project site](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax). Latest version 2.0.30506.0 works just fine with jQuery 1.9.1 for me.
Additional NuGet help from their docs at http://docs.nuget.org/.

Comment: AFAIK, I have the latest version. See my jsfiddle, in the external file. I get it from this place: http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js

Comment: Yeah that's old I see. I assumed you use the NuGet one as it comes with MVC4 (might be still the old Javascript unobtrusive for MVC 3). I'll update above with details. I don't see CDN versions for this, so you might have to use your own anyways.